# Adding Consecutive integers in Python, with a twist

Tags: python

Here is my original code:

```
x = input("Please input an integer: ")
x = int(x)
i = 1
sum = 0
while x >= i:
    sum = sum + i
    i += 1
print(sum)
```

Here is what the second part is:

**b) Modify your program by enclosing your loop in another loop so that you can find consecutive sums. For example , if 5 is entered, you will find five sum of consecutive numbers so that:**

```
1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
```

I have been stuck on this for 3 days now, and I just can't understand how to do it. I have tried this but to no avail.

```
while x >= i:
    sum_numbers = sum_numbers + i
    past_values = range(i)
    for ints in past_values:
        L = []
        L.append(ints)
        print(L, "+", i, "=", sum_numbers)
    i += 1
```

Can anyone just help steer my in the correct direction? BTW. it is python 3.3

Comment: You mean that for every integer entered you want to print out the sum of all positive integers less than or equal to that integer?

Comment: `range(5)` doesn't include `5` only 0,1,2,3,4.

Comment: @GarryCairns I don't want the answer, I just want to understand the thinking behind it.

Comment: @Ben For every integer (i) in the range of say 5, I want to print out: previous i values + i = sum of consecutive ints. I dont know how to to  get the previous i's

Comment: @Leealis in that case, the idea you want to look into is recursion. More specifically, recursive functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in one loop, by using `range` to define your numbers, and `sum` to loop through the numbers for you.

```
>>> x = input("Please input an integer: ")
Please input an integer: 5
>>> x = int(x)
>>>
>>> for i in range(1, x+1):
...     nums = range(1, i+1)
...     print(' + '.join(map(str, nums)), '=', sum(nums))
...
1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
```

`range(1, x+1)` would give me `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, this acts as the controller for how many times we want to print out a sum. So, this for loop will happen 5 times for your example.

`nums = range(1, i+1)` notice we are using `i` instead here, (taken from the `range` above), which I am using to define which number I am up to in the sequence.

`' + '.join(map(str, nums))`:

- `map(str, nums)` is used to convert all elements of `nums` into strings using `str`, since the `join` method expects an iterable filled with strings.
- `' + '.join` is used to "join" elements together with a common string, in this case, ' + '. In cases where there is only 1 element, `join` will just return that element.

`sum(nums)` is giving you the sum of all numbers defined in `range(1, i+1)`:

- When nums = `range(1, 2)`, `sum(nums)` = 1
- When nums = `range(1, 3)`, `sum(nums)` = 3
- Etc...

Comment: Thanks for the great breakdown of what the `map()` and `.join()` functions do. I'd give you an upvote if i could :/

Comment: @Leealis It's no problem :). I just updated the `print` statement since you said you were using Python3.

Answer (score 0):

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,range(x+1))
```

Comment: Please give a bit of context or explanation to your code, to make it better understandable.

Comment: why `reduce` if `n * (n + 1) / 2` does the job?

Comment: It creates the list of the numbers from 0 to x, then sums them and returns the result. I think the code is pretty much straightforward. Of course it is much slower than what suggested, because it loops.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a while loop, 2 for will do the trick nicely and with a more natural feeling.

```
x = input("Please input an integer : ")
x = int(x)
item = range(1, x + 1)
for i in item:
    sum = 0
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        sum = sum + j
    print(str(sum))
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Btw is there any relevance to why to you do `print(str(sum))` at the end. Why not just `print(sum)`?

Answer (score 0):

> Using list comprehension in python:

```
x = input("Please input an integer: ")
x = int(x)
i = 1

sums = [(((1+y)*y)//2) for y in range(i, x+1)] # creates list of integers
print(sums) # prints list of sums on one line
```

OR

```
[print(((1+y)*y)//2) for y in range(i, x+1)] # prints sums on separate line
```